# AngularJS validation directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a validation directive that we use to validate the controls on Blur and viewContentLoaded event.

We persist the form values in local storage to remember the details when we navigate away from the form and come back

The problem is that, even though it remembers the details it doesn't re-validate the Firstname and Lastname when we load that view again.

Following is our original code:

```
<div>
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <label class="control-label">First name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="firstName" name="FirstName" ng-model="order.FirstName" type="text" validate="alphabeticOnly" maxLength="30" required/>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.FirstName.$dirty && form.FirstName.$invalid">Please enter valid Firstname</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Last name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="lastName" name="LastName" ng-model="order.LastName" type="text" validate="alphabeticOnly" maxLength="30" required/>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.LastName.$dirty && form.LastName.$invalid">Please enter valid Lastname</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Confirm

The next function just saves the order and redirects to another page.

We have a $watch on $scope.order that saves the data in local storage to remember.

Directive:

```
  .directive('validate', ['validationService', function(validationService) {

function validate(elm) {
  var fn = elm.attr("validate");
  var value = elm.val();
  return validationService[fn](value);
}

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

      function triggerValidations(){
          checkValidity();
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
              checkValidity();
              return viewValue;
          });
          ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue) {
              checkValidity();
              return viewValue;
          });
      }

      function checkValidity(){
          if (elm.val().length > 0)
          {
              var isValid = validate(elm);
              ctrl.$setValidity('validate', isValid);
              console.log(" here i am - CheckValidity", attrs.id, elm.val(),  isValid );
              //scope.$apply();
          }
      }

  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', triggerValidations);

    elm.bind('blur', function(event) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$setValidity('validate', validate(elm));
      });
    });

  }
};
```

}])

If we add $scope.apply it gives an error "$digest already in progress"

At the end, we want to validate the form when someone lands onto the page.

Comment: try using `$timeout` before triigering first validation

Comment: In the very last bit of code where you `unshift()` onto `$parsers`, why do you only call `ctrl.$setValidity()` if the validation passes? Shoulden't that just be doing: `ctrl.$setValidity('validate', validate(elm));` ?

Comment: Sorry about that one, but it was older implementation that we forgot to remove from this example. We tried using $timeout as well but no luck.